# Chartist donut chart labels misplaced

Tags: chartist.js

When I draw a simple donut chart and increase the font sizes of the labels they get unevenly placed.

Tried to compensate with the settings but that just make one of the labels even more misplaced. Is this a bug or can it be fixed?

```
{
    donut: true,
    labelOffset: -5
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gx55mo6b/2/